# Failed RAM upgrade

Tags: memory, upgrade

I tried to upgrade the RAM on my desktop, but it fails to boot.

The motherboard (ASUS M3A78-T) supports ECC RAM,

To build a home server, I bought 4 of the following:

> Hynix HYMP125P72CP4-S5 AB (2GB, DDR2-800Mhz, 1Rx4, PC2-6400P) Brand
>   details: HP (499276-061) 501157-001 ECC REG

I matched everything I read was important: the DDR generation, the clock speed and the maximum slot capacity.

...Can anyone tell me why the upgrade failed? Does anything not match the motherboard?

From the [motherboard manual](http://ftp.tekwind.co.jp/pub/asustw/mb/socketAM2/M3A78/E4413_M3A78_v3-manual.zip):

> 1.7.2  Memory Configurations You may install 256MB, 512MB, 1GB, and 2GB unbuffered ECC/non-ECC DDR2 DIMMs into the DIMM sockets.

Also: A list of approved 800Mhz RAM from the manual (below)

Thank you

[image: List of approved 800Mhz RAM from the manual]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to superuser. What is your CPU in your motherboard? Not all CPU accept ECC ram.

Comment: Hi, it's an AMD Phenom X4 9550

Comment: Your CPU has no ECC support...

Comment: Look at Kingston, https://www.kingston.com/us , or Crucial, https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/memory-info , to find compatible RAM .

Comment: @NatsuKage, No, I knew I had read this somewhere, but all AMD Phenom/Athlon/Ryzen CPUs support ECC: "Integrated Memory Controller": "ECC checking with double-bit detect and single-bit correct" from AMD Data sheet: 
 http://static.highspeedbackbone.net/pdf/46878_Phenom_II_PDS_3.04_PUB.pdf Also: Hardware forum 1: https://hardforum.com/threads/ecc-ram-support-question.1639536/ Hardware forum 2: https://www.xigmanas.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13562#p84329

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! I couldn't actually find a website that said it supported ECC. But the datasheet is useful. And yeah....I hope you get to resell those registered dimms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RAM is [registered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory) and the specifications for your motherboard require unbuffered DIMMs.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought I had overlooked something.